# Node: ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

The source code is :

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env["DSN"]);
```

When trying to exec **via node** (**I insist, I'm not trying to exec this code in my browser**), I get :

```
$ node Sequelize.js
file:///Users/snwfdhmp/project/Sequelize.js:1
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
                  ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at file:///Users/snwfdhmp/project/Sequelize.js:1:19
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:138:23)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:178:24)
```

Why does that happen ? Every article on the internet says "Don't use require() in browsers", but I'm not using a browser.

I'm using node v14.4.0 on macOS 10.15.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you defined `"type": "module"` in your **package.json**, you should remove it.

The reason is, certain CommonJS variables are not available in ES modules ([reference](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_no_require_exports_module_exports_filename_dirname)),
these are:

```
require
exports
module.exports
__filename
__dirname
```

However, `require` can be imported into an ES module using [module.createRequire()](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_createrequire_filename).